# Cant send message by using pykafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, pykafka

I am using pykafka, I can get topic names but I cant send message. My code is shown below

```
client = KafkaClient(hosts='xx.xx.xx.xx:9092')
topic = client.topics['test']
producer = topic.get_sync_producer()
producer.produce(b"message")
```

And I get this error message

```
raise ProduceFailureError("Delivery report not received after timeout")
pykafka.exceptions.ProduceFailureError: Delivery report not received after timeout
```

Comment: Please share your broker configuration

Comment: broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092                                                                       I am sending to an external IP message consumer borker configuration is here. I have one broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     broker.id=1
>     listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
> ```
>
> I am sending to an external IP message

If you are setting `hosts=some.external.IP:9092`, then you need to edit Kafka properties with `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://some.external.IP:9092` and make `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092` to listen on external interfaces.

Listing the topics uses a different protocol, which is why it works fine.

Comment: You mean I need to write as                                                                                      client = KafkaClient(hosts='externalmachineIP:9092') for producer.                                                                                                                                         And for consumer  advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://locahost:9092 and  listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Comment: No changes should be needed to your code. You need to update the server.properties file and restart kafka